# GMAail smtp doesn't work on another PC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gmail, smtpclient

I have a problem when i try to call this method in app.
It works when the app is on my PC (where was write this code) but when i send app to another client(PC) this doesn't work anymore.

I tried with every port(465,587,25,2525) to more PC.
I think is something wrong with connection to the smtp server.

Any idea why it doesn't work to another PC?

```
private void materialFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (indexfeedback == 0)
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
            const string fromPassword = "password";
            const string subject = "Subject";
            const string body = "Body";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
                label444.Text = "SEND !!!";
            }


            indexfeedback++;
        }
        else
        {
            label234.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help !
I tried for 2 hours at my office to searching for a solution but i didn't find anything

Comment: *doesn't work on another PC* is **not** a technical description of a problem

Comment: sorry, i'm new in this and i have no idea how to explain this problem well

Comment: i've tried to call this method to another PC at my office and doesn't want to work and then i send the app to a friend with personal PC and again doesn't work ..

Comment: Well, we just have no information to go by. Do you get an error, does it crash, does it all work and just no email, does it end up in a junk mail folder. can you send to any other email address?

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? We can't help if we don't know -what- went wrong

Comment: Don't try random ports. The *server* doesn't change. GMail isn't just any SMTP server though. The *user* has to authorize its use. If you search for `gmail` and the actual error message you'll find many duplicates

Comment: This is the error :
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com'
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: @RazvanBarbu that's a DNS error. It means that machine can't find the server. Probably doesn't even have a connection. This is a networking problem, it can't be solved by code.

Comment: Thanks, but the machine have a connection because i write this message from the machine with problem, but now i'm gonna to try some of this solutions you advice maybe could help me

Comment: Can you ping the address? Command prompt -> ping smtp.gmail.com. It should give you several reply messages.

Comment: @WynDiesel i tried this now and give me this message : Ping could not find host smtp.gmail.com. Please check the name and try again...

Comment: That means that network cant reach gmail's smtp address. Something is preventing the computer from understanding that smtp.google.com needs to point to an IP address, so it's a networking problem.

Comment: ok, thank you so much, it is possible to be some Renault protocols in this building..but still does this at my friend machine which is at his home...

Comment: Thanks, i found the issue.  Here in Renault building(Bucharest) the network connection have some transfer data protocols which prevents the connection to smtp.gmail.com server and at my friend the problem is with firewall which has the same problem.    Thank for every answer to this qestion ! :)